# What providers is better for mobile backend private API hosting?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, backendless, mbaas, built.io

I'm looking at creating a private API for my mobile app to interact with my postgres db. But I have no idea what hosting should I go for? I looked around and shortlist Amazon Mobile Hub, Backendless, and Built.io

Which is better among the three? Initially i wanted to go for Firebase but looks like the data is out there is not really private. but that's the same for any cloud hosting is it? Any ways to circumvent this?